# How to defragment RAM by command in text file

Tags: windows-xp, memory

In the old days: 99' I used utility to free some RAM memory but I remember that there is also a command which invoked can force Windows XP(then Windows 98SE) to free some RAM.

Does anybody remembers this method?

Answer (score 3):

It is not necessary to defragment the RAM. A simple reboot would have the same effect. Programs that defragment the RAM memory are useless or even damage your system.

Comment: There is 1GB RAM and Firefox takes 600MB and I need it to manage its memory. 600MB is lot of data even for 20 tabs.

Comment: This might help you: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-uses-too-much-memory-ram